# Chrome devtools extension console

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I included this in my chrome extension manifest

```
"devtools_page": "devtools.html"
```

And in devtools.html I include a devtools.js file which creates a panel

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("Panel", "icon.png", "panel.html", function(panel){});
```

The panel is indeed created. And in panel.html I include a panel.js file in which I added a listener

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(function(details){
    console.log(details);
});
```

But where can I see the console output of the panel? Or how can I redirect it to the devtools console?

Answer (score 25):

This message will be logged in the console of the developer tools. To view this console, detach the developer tools from the window, and press Ctrl + Shift + J.

Here's an picture:

```
1. Page (http://host/)
2. + Devtools instance for http://host
3.   + Devtools instance for chrome-devtools://devtools/devtools.html?... )
```

Your message is currently logged to 3 (the console of the devtools instance) instead of 2 (the console of the page). To log the string to the page, use the [`chrome.experimental.devtools.console`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.devtools.console.html) API.

An alternative is to JSON-serialize your object, and use [`chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/devtools_inspectedWindow/#method-eval) to log the result:

```
var obj = ...;
var str = JSON.stringify( obj );
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval('console.log(' + str + ');');
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is to open the chrome devtools in a separate window (not on the side of the browser) and then press `CMD + Option + i` (for Mac) and then you get another devtools for that devtools. There you can debug and see console logs easier :)