# Why no logs in the console for Chrome devtools extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm making a [Chrome devtools extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools). I make a simple devtools page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  Foobar. <script>console.log('foobar');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I specify `"devtools_page": "dev-tools.html"` in manifest.json. However, nothing prints in the console. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [By default](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution), inline script won't be executed. You could extract the scripts to a external js file and include that using `<script></script>`
2. Detach the F12 tool and press Ctrl+Shift+J(Windows) to view your console (shortcuts [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts?hl=en)). More details you can find from this answer: [Chrome devtools extension console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801693/chrome-devtools-extension-console)

Comment: Thank you. Both 1 and 2 were necessary. After 1, I was logging into the console of the dev tools itself, which sounds really meta, but hey. I had to detach dev tools into its own window, then use Ctrl + Shift + J to open the console ... for the console.